# Tree property at weak inaccessibles

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, trees

Suppose $\kappa$ is a weakly inaccessible cardinal with the tree property.  What can we say about the height of $\kappa$?  Is it a weakly-hyper-Mahlo of some sort?  Does it enjoy some kind of indescribability property?  Of course it is weakly compact in $L$, but I am interested in what height properties we can say it has in a universe where $\kappa$ is not strongly inaccessible.

Comment: By the work of Boos, the least weakly Mahlo cardinal can have the tree property.

Comment: I think it is open if the least weakly inaccessible can have the tree property.

Comment: What is the height of $\kappa$?

Comment: @MohammadGolshani Great! Can you give a reference?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I just mean some description of “how many” cardinals are below $\kappa$, like not only $\kappa$-many but stationary many regulars, and moreover a stationary many with that property, blah blah.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In his paper [Boolean extensions which efface the Mahlo property](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/boolean-extensions-which-efface-the-mahlo-property1/34045FCF82EA845DDB2F3A1E6D393211) William Boos proves the following consistency result:

**Theorem.** Assume GCH holds and $\kappa$ is weakly compact. Then there exists a cardinal preserving generic extension of the universe in which $\kappa$ is the least weakly Mahlo cardinal and the tree property holds at $\kappa$.

The proof of the theorem is very similar to that of Mitchell, the main difference is that at Mahlo cardinals below $\kappa$ he adds a club of singular cardinals into that cardinal.

The following is asked in the paper and is still open:

**Question.** Is it consistent that the tree property hold at the least weakly inaccessible cardinal?

Comment: In my last visit of Vienna, Yair and I discussed this question and Yair had some ideas, but we could not find any other time to discuss it again. He may give some more information about the question.